# Couchbase N1QL query always return empty and dropping-recreating primary index fails

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

This is the second time it happens, it was solved by re-installing couchbase last time, but I think I need to figure out the reason.

I only use one small bucket for testing (less than 500 documents), so I don't think this is related to ram/disk usage. It worked fine until a point when all queries fail to return anything(all queries return empty)

Queries like

```
select MYBUCKET.* from MYBUCKET where someBool == false order by date desc
```

and

```
delete from MYBUCKET
```

does not do anything at all, even the delete query won't delete anything. Weirdly, no error returned.

I tried to drop the primary index, it shows timeout but actually succeed.
Then I tried to create primary index again, this is the error message i got.

> GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Encounter errors during create index. Error=Request timed out. Index server may still be processing this request. Please check the status after sometime or retry. .

Is there any log or anything I should provide to help with debugging?

PS

- The queries are executed in admin page(`http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html#!/query/workbench`)
- Using C# SDK to execute the query also result in the same.
- Restarting does not solve the problem.

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server?

Comment: @MatthewGroves Community Edition 5.0.1 build 5003

Comment: You might want to take a look at the logs and see if anything stands out. Info on logs here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/clustersetup/ui-logs.html I would focus on `indexer` and maybe `error`,`debug`,`info`